# Delete Table in Existing Connections in Excel

Tags: excel

I created a new connection `'ticketFile'` with PowerQuery. It appeared in a new sheet in my excel file. As I didn't want this data to be shown in a sheet (but still wanted it to exist), I just deleted the sheet.

And now I get an error each time I do a refresh All :
`We couldn't get the data from 'ticketFile' in the workbook 'C:\[...]\Biweekly Reports.xlsx'.`

I found out in the existing connections

[image: Excel screenshot]

Now I'm trying to delete the ticketFile table without having any access to it. How should I do this ?

Comment: Can you not do Data > Connections > Delete it?

Comment: I don't see any "Connection" option. There is "Existing Connections" (from the screenshot), "Queries & connections" in which the table does not appear (only the connection, which I need to keep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that in some manipulation I created a new Connection named `WorksheetConnection_Biweekly Reports.xlsx!csv`.

(**Note:** I found the connections at `Data -> Queries & Connections` it seems it is not always the case depending on the version of Excel you are using.)

[image] [image]

When looking at its proprieties I did find the same Locations that in the main `ThisWorkbookDataModel` and the `ticketFile` table I wanted to delete did not appear in it. So at first I didn't think the problem was there.

But spoilers:

> It was

Deleting the `WorksheetConnection_Biweekly Reports.xlsx!csv` solved my issue without inferfering with any of my PivotTables.

Comment: Thanks to @QHarr for his time and help on this !

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

- Go to existing connection
- Select 'Browse for more'
- While file open dialogue box will open then select the existing file links and just press 'delete' button.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem. I solved it by editing the internal file 'workbook.xml' (unzipped) of the Excel Workbook, cleaning the contents (but not deleting it) of the tag . There was the specification to a "External data 3". After, I zipped it out again. Re-opening in Excel there was a warning message. I clicked on "Yes" and then the dialog reporting the rescue appeared. I Clicked 'OK' and saved the file. Done.